# I would like to convert Chinese text to Unicode code points

Tags: delphi

hello everyone I have this Chinese text "请检查是否安装客户端" I would like to know how can I make it look like this "\u5fae\u4fe1APP\u5524\u8d77\u6210\u529f" I am using delphi 10.2 I am grateful for any help

Comment: Use Ord and convert the 16 bit values to hex

Comment: I wonder which of those graphemes translates to `APP`. Also: what have you tried so far and where do you fail? Where's your code?

Comment: I used this code 
LJSONValue:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ent),0);

to make this "\ u5fae for this" 微 "I would like to do the reverse

Comment: The number of characters in your converted text is 9 while in Chinese it is 10. I guess the conversion is not correct. What do you think about this one: "\u8BF7\u68C0\u67E5\u662F\u5426\u5B89\u88C5\u5BA2\u6237\u7AEF"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of characters in your converted text is 9 while in Chinese it is 10. I guess the conversion is not correct. What do you think about this one: "\u8BF7\u68C0\u67E5\u662F\u5426\u5B89\u88C5\u5BA2\u6237\u7AEF"?

The above conversion is done like this:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    S1 : String;
    S2 : String;
    C  : Char;
begin
    S1 := '请检查是否安装客户端';
    Memo1.Lines.Add(S1);

    S2 := '';
    for C in S1 do
        S2 := S2 + '\u' + IntToHex(Ord(C), 4);

    Memo1.Lines.Add(S2);
end;
```